# Broadcom component library for Eagle circuit design software?

Tags: eaglecad

I can not find any broadcom components in Eagle, can some be download to be imported?

Comment: When in doubt make it. What part do you need?

Comment: BCM2835.Kinda hard to make.

Comment: Yeah, that's not really something you'll find in a common library. You have to look for that specifically or look for raspberry pi footprints.

Comment: The full datasheet is hard to come by.  There is this page: http://elinux.org/RPi_BCM2835_Pinout  although it isn't confirmed

Comment: Thank you, I see no reason for them to hide the data sheet?

Comment: The Pi gerbers can also be found. If you wanted you could look at a gerber viewer and reverse engineer the footprint at the least.

Comment: Wow, didn't realize it was so difficult to find anything on the Pi. The gerbers are only available in picture form, so any actual gerber data is lost. You could piece together distances and infer length, but when you need really accurate BGA pitch it's a risk.

Comment: Exactly, even the Upverter part concierge don't want to make the part, its not looking good...

Comment: It is more so broadcom being incredibly secretive.  If you aren't a company that is going to buy 10K units, they don't see the point in releasing their documentation

Comment: Well then, what a anti-social approach. How can you develop something to ever buy 10k units? I mean if the part is not available on any circuit design software and the data sheet is non existent, makes no sense does it?

Comment: Yes, essentially what it means if you aren't big enough to have the potential they won't take you. You go in and say hey here's my projected number of units, my projected profit, let me see your stuff. An NDA is signed, etc.

Comment: By the way, why do you want the footprint/schematic file? Specific project?

Comment: Just make your own. Eagle's tools for building your own components is very easy to use.

Comment: I am just experimenting with arm and cortex, decided to settle on the ARM Cortex A8, any one know where I could find some documenting about the use of a HDMI socket and the arm a8? all I can seem to find is that it supports it, but not how its done, I know that some sort of encoder is required.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is as close as we get to an answer for now. Broadcom chips are not released to the public with footprints and pinout. I, however, am fascinated in trying to get something workable. I looked up pdf to gerber converters, as it is popular and found this...
http://swannman.github.io/pdf2gerb/

I am not in the mood to install perl on my Windows machine right now, but if someone wants to give it a shot, they can get gerbers for the top layer. Try taking some pics of the top layer, converting to pdf and running them through...
http://elinux.org/RPi_BCM2835_Pinout
https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/final-pcb-artwork/

This is the first step. If someone gets a clean gerber, then you can use relative distances from measurements on a Pi board to get the gerber spacing. Do this yourself or send me a clean gerber. With all of this, it would be possible to create a proper BGA footprint with decent pin pitches.

With the work done on the previously linked Linux page (thanks @FunkGuy), we might have something here.

Comment: I will try that, macs ship with Python.